# PATH を通しても gitコマンドを読み込まない

Tags: windows, git

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin` と `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` の両方を PATH に通して、再起動した後でも gitコマンドを読み込みません。なぜでしょうか。

**エラーメッセージ**
'git' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

**環境**
OS: Windows10

Comment: gitforwindowsはインストール時に選べたと思いますが、その時はonlyGitbashを選んだのでしょうか？

Comment: 追加した PATH の下に `git.exe` は存在していますか？

Comment: gitを使ったことがないですが、CMDに`where git`命令でgitのパスを出力できますか。

Comment: @Light さん
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
が出力されます

Comment: @keitaro_so さん
覚えていないので再インストールしてみます

Comment: @cubick さん
両方とも存在しています

Comment: @keitaro_so さん
いいえ、
Git from the command line and also from 3rd-party software(Recommended) を選択しています。

Comment: Windowsのpathの設定は文字列長さに制限があります(ガンガン追加はできるのですが、一つにまとめると長すぎる場合があります)。コマンドラインで"path"と打ってみて、ご自身が設定したpathが含まれているか確認してみてください。

Comment: 「gitコマンドを読み込みません」とは具体的にどんな操作を行った結果でしょうか？ / Git for Windows のインストールで git bash を使っているなら、Windows に対しての PATH 設定は影響あるのかが気になりました。

Comment: cubickさんが指摘済みですが「gitコマンドを読み込まない」というのがどのような行為・結果を求めているのかがわかりませんでした。求めるゴールがわからない以上、回答もできないと思います。

Comment: @SugiyamaKoichi さん
含まれています。

Comment: 「gitを読み込まない」とは git init のコマンドで
「'git' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。」
と表示されることを意味します。

Comment: 解決済みですが、Git Bashで動作するのであれば、質問文にある「PATH に通して」の操作が実際には不完全でPATHが通っていなかったことが原因と思われます。これに関しては具体的な操作が提示されないことには詳細は分かりません。

Comment: sayuriさんのご指摘通り、根本的な解決ではありませんでした。今になって解決したので回答をしました。@sayuri

Answer (score 1):

ユーザの環境変数にはパスを通していたが
システムの環境変数にパスを通していなかったことが原因でした。

システムの環境変数にパスを通したところ、gitのコマンドが実行されるようになりました。

（なぜユーザの環境変数に通したものが実行されないのか、また不明ですが

Answer (score 0):

コマンドプロンプトから実行しようとしていませんか？Windows の場合、基本的には **Git Bash** から `git` コマンドを使用することになります。

スタートメニュー -> Git -> Git Bash

Comment: Git Bash からだとできました。